# @property (nonatomic, assign) id <IconDownloaderDelegate> delegate;

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Anyone can explain me what this line mean ? I use to see (nonatomic,retain) it's first time I see the "assign" keyword in:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <IconDownloaderDelegate> delegate;
```

Thx for your help,

Stephane

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on Peter's answer:

When you create a property, you can automatically create getter and setter methods with the `@synthesize` directive.  The compiler not only creates two methods

```
 - (id) delegate;
 - (void) setDelegate: (id) newDelegate;
```

but also puts extra code around this to prevent multiple threads from changing the property at the same time (essentially a lock).  `nonatomic` tells the compiler that the code does not need to be thread safe, which means less code and better performance.

A setter created by the compiler with `retain` would look something like this:

```
- (void) setDelegate: (id) newDelegate {
    if (delegate != newDelegate) {
        [delegate release];
        delegate = [newDelegate retain]; 
    }
}
```

and is why you need to release retained properties in the `dealloc` method of your class.

Since the general advice is to not retain your delegate, you use `assign` instead of `retain` and the setter would look like this:

```
- (void) setDelegate: (id) newDelegate {
    if (delegate != newDelegate) {
        delegate = newDelegate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First i thought to explain you here but i found this **[link](http://bit.ly/257PEv)** and think might clear your doubt in well.

**[assign](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW13)**

Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This attribute is the default.

You typically use this attribute for scalar types such as NSInteger and CGRect, or (in a reference-counted environment) for objects you don’t own, such as delegates.

retain and assign are effectively the same in a garbage-collected environment.

Answer (score 1):

Assign is simply an assignment like int x = y with no memory management (like with retain).